# Propel filtering based on joined tables columns?

Tags: php, propel

How do I filter based on a joined table's columns in Propel?

Like:

```
$results = FooQuery::create()->joinBar()->filterByBarSurname('surname');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `use` method as described [in the doc](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#embedding_a_related_query):

```
$results = FooQuery::create()
  ->useBarQuery()
    ->filterBySurname('surname')
  ->endUse()
  ->find();

// example Query generated for a MySQL database
$query = 'SELECT foo.* from foo
INNER JOIN bar ON foo.BAR_ID = bar.ID
WHERE bar.SURNAME = :p1'; // :p1 => 'surname'
```

If you **have to** use `join()`, I don't think you can use `filterByXXX` method but the old `where`:

```
$results = FooQuery::create()
  ->join('Foo.Bar')
  ->where('Bar.surname = ?', 'surname')
  ->find();
```

Comment: Just a quick question. What if you can't call that method and have to use `join()`?

Comment: Well then you will have to use the old way with `where` instead of `filterByXXX`.

Comment: There shouldn't be a time where you can't use a table query object unless you've made a mistake in your schema in relating tables that should be related.  You can use these query objects at any depth by cascading the use statements.